# I want check internet connection before every dio request using interceptor and connectivity package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check the internet connection before every dio request using the interceptor and connectivity package in Flutter

Answer (score 1):

1.First you should Install `connectivity` package into you'r project.you can add it using bellow cammand,

```
flutter pub add connectivity_plus
```

2.Now you should import into you'r workspace. import

```
'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
```

you can refer it by using this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus/versions/3.0.6/install).

3.Set up an interceptor to check the internet connection before each Dio request. Create a class that extends `Interceptor` from Dio package: look at bellow code segment,

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

class ConnectivityInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  final Connectivity connectivity;

  ConnectivityInterceptor(this.connectivity);

  @override
  Future onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    var connectivityResult = await connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      // Handle case when there is no internet connection
      throw DioError(
        requestOptions: options,
        response: Response(
          requestOptions: options,
          statusCode: 503, // You can set your custom status code
          statusMessage: 'No internet connection',
        ),
      );
    }
    return super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }
}
```

4.In your main function or where you configure Dio, set up the Dio instance with the interceptor:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

void main() {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  Connectivity connectivity = Connectivity();
  dio.interceptors.add(ConnectivityInterceptor(connectivity));
  
  runApp(MyApp(dio: dio));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Dio dio;

  MyApp({required this.dio});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dio Connectivity Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              makeDioRequest();
            },
            child: Text('Make Dio Request'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> makeDioRequest() async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get('https://api.example.com/data');
      print('Response: ${response.data}');
      // Handle the response
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response != null && e.response!.statusCode == 503) {
        // Handle case when there is no internet connection
        print('No internet connection');
        // Show a dialog or snackbar indicating no internet
      } else {
        // Handle other Dio errors
        print('Dio error: $e');
        // Show a dialog or snackbar with the error
      }
    }
  }
}

class ConnectivityInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  final Connectivity connectivity;

  ConnectivityInterceptor(this.connectivity);

  @override
  Future onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    var connectivityResult = await connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      // Handle case when there is no internet connection
      throw DioError(
        requestOptions: options,
        response: Response(
          requestOptions: options,
          statusCode: 503, // You can set your custom status code
          statusMessage: 'No internet connection',
        ),
      );
    }
    return super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }
}
```

I use simple app with button, you can give some idea using this guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the purpose why you wanna use the `interceptor` and `connectivity` packages(ignore the answer if you have specific purpose using for them), but for simply checking is internet connection is available or not, i use `InternetAddress.lookup` from `dart:io` library like below:

```
/// [_isInternetAvailable] Checks if the
/// internet connection is available or not.
Future<bool> _isInternetAvailable() async {
  try {
    final foo = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
    return foo.isNotEmpty && foo[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty ? true : false;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Since the Dio package does not handle internet connection error. I want to check the internet connection before every dio API request.(globally)

Comment: Than using `InternetAddress.lookup` is better, cause it don't require any additional package.